# Would endless scroll on popup be a bad UI?

Tags: scrolling, popup

I want to use popup to present the user activities. The list might be long and I wonder if scrolling on popup is ok.

Comment: We could use some more detail here (use case, platform) but popup seems like a very poor choice.

Comment: Scrolling on any page element should be avoided in most cases, but like the others say, we need more information. If your required content does not fit in a popup, its probably better to redirect to an 'details' or 'edit' page.

Answer (score 0):

If a popup is a good idea depends on several things. If you could provide more information about the context, I will try to answer your question more specific. For now, I will try to explain when a popup is appropriate and when it's not.

First we have to look at what a pop up exactly is. It is a disruptive dialogue form the computer to the user, placed on top of everything, showing the user a piece of information (eg. document is not saved) and optionally asking a question (eg. do you really want to quit?). To determine if a pop-up is the right choice you have to ask yourself 'Can the process proceed without the users input?'. If the answer is yes (eg. your mail has been send), a notification somewhere on the screen will do fine. If the answer is no, a pop-up is probably a good idea. An example of a good popup implementation is asking the user if he really wants to quit if there is an unsaved document.

I don't see any major problems with scrolling in a pop-up except for too much content. However, infinite scroll does feel as a bit much. The temporary character of the popup doesn't really suit an infinite scroll. Maybe if the user has full control over when the popup will appear... It also raises other questions like, what happens with the scroll position when the user closes the popup and reopens it.